# Plot generated in Octave is fully black

Tags: plot, gnuplot, octave, fedora, gnu

I am using **octave 4.2.1** on **fedora 26**.

(I recently upgraded from fedora 25 to 26 and through this octave was upgraded from 4.0.3 to 4.2.1)

Now when I plot a figure like `plot(x)`the figure that comes up is just a black image. Before the up gradation i didn't had this problem.
I am attaching a snapshot also

[image].

How can i correct it?

Comment: Which version of gnuplot do you have? Relevant:http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42838

Comment: @SardarUsama Name         : gnuplot
Version      : 5.0.5
Release      : 4.fc26
Arch         : x86_64
Size         : 1.9 M
Source       : gnuplot-5.0.5-4.fc26.src.rpm

Comment: From the image above I see that you are using the Qt toolkit so gnuplot is irrelevant here. You can try to switch to FLTK with `graphics_toolkit("fltk")` or gnuplot before plotting (make sure to `close all` before). Are you using Mesa based GPU drivers or proprietary drivers like the NVIDIA ones? Is glxgears running fine? Do you see any warnings when starting the GUI from a terminal? Do you see the same when using the CLI (`octave --no-gui`)?

Answer (score 20):

change your graphics_toolkit

```
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")
```

Or

```
graphics_toolkit("qt")
```

Or

```
graphics_toolkit("fltk")
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. `graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")` was what worked for me. Both `qt` and `fltk` returned blank screens.